# Best way to code CSS3 Shadows?

Tags: css

I'm trying to style up this heading. It slightly pops out the side with a shadow to give it a 3D effect. Please see below:

[image: What I'm trying to code.]

I am trying to avoid cropping a background-image, for performance reasons and I like to code in progressive enhancement fashion.

I am thinking of making the right and bottom into a border but then what technique can I achieve to get the right hand edge? Is it possible to use CSS3 to produce this design?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thats as close I could get throwing some css together off the top of my head:
Might need some vendor-prefixes added, but works till IE7.

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/poikl/3Craj/4/)

edit: corrected fiddle.

Comment: This is awesome! Perfect for what I need. You're a genius, didn't think of using pseudo-class :before. Thanks for the help

Comment: @StevenWu Again: Depending on which browser you want to support you need the according browser-prefixes and for IE you need the `MS-Filter` property + helper-tag for IE7/6 (they cant handle pseudoclasses). But IE7+6 can be omitted on nomral (non-commercial/professional) pages.

Comment: Just realise this fix doesn't quite work on Firefox. I even tried to put in -moz prefix but still no luck

Comment: @StevenWu corrected fiddle. I guess you could have done this on your own...;)

Comment: how did you fix that? Its working in Firefox now. Also why does 'border:5px solid red;' hide the shadow? when its red and not white?

Comment: @StevenWu FF has problems with negative blur-radius, so i changed the values for spread-radius to 0 and blur-radius to 0 too. (was -5px 5px). The red border gets overriden by the following rule `border-color`

Answer (score 0):

With the two way, border and shadow you ll have some trouble, look at my fiddle : 
http://jsfiddle.net/DoubleYo/nYKn3/

I ll try a third method withe :before to put a seconde div under

Comment: This the same trouble I encountered.